# Access HTML element attribute in Angular template

Tags: angular

I would like to use the HTML element property value directly in the angular template.

My draft now looks like

```
<button
  #next
  accesskey="Y"
  (click)="clickHandler()">

      Do something ({{nextButton.nativeElement.accessKeyLabel}})

</button>
```

The `nextButton` is initialised in the component with a ViewChild('next')

Is something like that even possible, or is creating a separate field with the extracted attribute value the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `accessKeyLabel` only in template you no need to define viewChild in `ts` you can directly access attribute using template variable.

```
<button
  #next
  accesskey="Y"
  (click)="clickHandler()">
      Do something ({{next.accessKeyLabel}})
</button>
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hhonhi?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Comment: Thank you, that's true, it actually works! I wonder why I did't try it at the very beginning...

Comment: Glad it worked for you. We all overlook simple solutions sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add null checking `?.` and access the property directly, without view child!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <button
    #next
    accesskey="Y"
    (click)="clickHandler()">

        Do something ({{ next?.accessKey }})

  </button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  clickHandler() {
    alert('clicked');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2pxubw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)